# OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)

Tags: debugging, tensorflow

I am getting the outOfRange error when trying to feed the data to the model. I am guessing that data never reaches the queue, hence the error. Just for the testing I am feeding it the tfrecord with one tuple (image,ground_truth).
I also tried tensorflow debugger(tfdbg) but it would also just throw the same error I couldn't see any tensoeflow value.

Tensorflow version: 1.3

Python version: 3.5.3

Os: Windows10

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecord_filename],num_epochs=1)

image_batch, annotation_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([resized_image, resized_annotation],
                                                       batch_size=1,
                                                       capacity=10,
                                                       num_threads=1,
                                                       min_after_dequeue=1)
```

StackTrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/supriya.godge/PycharmProjects/tf-image-segmentation/tf_image_segmentation/recipes/pascal_voc/DeepLab/resnet_v1_101_8s_train.py", line 160, in <module>
    train_step])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'shuffle_batch', defined at:
  File "C:/Users/supriya.godge/PycharmProjects/tf-image-segmentation/tf_image_segmentation/recipes/pascal_voc/DeepLab/resnet_v1_101_8s_train.py", line 68, in <module>
    min_after_dequeue=1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 1220, in shuffle_batch
    name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 791, in _shuffle_batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 457, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1342, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

I have tried different solution posted on stackoverflow for the same error. Unfortunately nothing worked for me. Please let me know if I should provide any additional information. 
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the content of `tfrecord_filename`?

Comment: Remove num_epochs in tf.train.string_input_producer ?

Comment: @GPh tfrecord has 4 pairs of (image, ground_truth_image).

Comment: @Tianjin yah thanks for suggestion, but I tried that and it didn't work for me.

Comment: is there any way I can debug it and see tensor values ? I tried tfdbg but I couldn't find any way to put a breakpoint so I got the same above error in debugging as well. (there is only one conditional breakpoint in tfdbg but its for nan and inf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this url to create annotation image. Once you completed the annotation image, please see the matrix value to annotation image.

URL:https://github.com/kyamagu/js-segment-annotator

```
Example:
Originale Annotation Image Matrix Value [1,1,1] but
Your Annotation image have [0,0,1] or [1,0,0] or [0,1,0].
```

So you convert to same value[1,1,1] from [0,0,1] using my python script with opencv

```
def biggest(a, y, z):
    Max = a
    if y > Max:
        Max = y
    if z > Max:
        Max = z
        if y > z:
            Max = y
    return Max
#Input Image
outdir = "sampleimages/sample2.png"
cnt = 0
image = cv2.imread(outdir)

for i in range(0,360):
  for j in range(0,480):
    newvalue = biggest(image[i,j,0],image[i,j,1],image[i,j,2])
    image[i,j,0] = newvalue
    image[i,j,1] = newvalue
    image[i,j,2] = newvalue
    #if image[i,j] == 8:
    #  cnt += 1
#Output Image
cv2.imwrite("sampleimages/sample-gray-2.png",image)
```

Please Refer:
https://github.com/tkuanlun350/Tensorflow-SegNet/issues/6

Comment: Thank you for the information, it is definitely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a dataset for my machine learning project, and it turns out I get above error whenever I was saving the image file in png format from python.
I generated the dataset using the mat-lab and error vanished. I am still investigating this and post the updated answer soon. Meanwhile I hope this will be helpful to somebody.

Comment: did you solve the error with the above method? I'm still running into the problem.

Comment: Hi Moondra,
yes, I was able to solve this error by saving the png files using matlab.

Comment: Thanks. I actually deleted the .png files and I'm still running into the problem. I guess I will make a new thread about it.

Answer (score 0):

> If the Annotation image is wrong, this error will be shown. Please see
>   the annotation image matrix value. It should be differ. For example
>   the annotation image matrix value have gray color(matrix value[1 1 1])
>   but your image not gray(matix value[1 3 6]). So check the matrix value
>   of your annotation image
>
> If the annotation image is not gray, then queue is not fill. This is
>   the error.

Try this code in Inputs.py line 68 inside CamVid_reader_seq def

```
label_bytes = tf.image.decode_png(labelValue,1)
```

Note: 1 means convert color image to grayscale

Comment: Please read carefully here before posting answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who this might help, I was getting the same error and this is apparently the first link which talks about the error in a different context.

Thanks to **Tensorflow's poor error messages**, this error could be possible due to the following:

1. Bad path to TF records file
2. Image shape mis-match
3. Image file format mis-match